# Possible to set an initial value for a shader uniform? (Android, OpenGL ES 2.0)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader, uniform

**edit**: As suggested, I'm trying to set an 'initial' value to my shaders uniform in my constructor, I have included some code and would be grateful if someone could explain why I get a blank screen if I pass the values in via my constructor - thanks

**Method to load my texture**

```
public void setTexture(GLSurfaceView view, Bitmap imgTexture) {
    this.imgTexture=imgTexture;
    iProgId = Utils.LoadProgram(strVShader, strFShader);
    iBaseMap = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "u_baseMap");
    iPosition = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(iProgId, "a_position");
    iTexCoords = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(iProgId, "a_texCoords");
    texID = Utils.LoadTexture(view, imgTexture);

    //Everything is working if I include the lines as part of my setTexture() method
    GLES20.glUseProgram(iProgId);
    mOpacityHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "opValue");
    GLES20.glUniform1f(mOpacityHandle, 1.0f);
}
```

but if I place them in my constructor, nothing....

```
public Quad() {
    //iProgId = Utils.LoadProgram(strVShader, strFShader); //I've tried with and without this line - I can confirm that loading / linking is working OK
    GLES20.glUseProgram(iProgId);
    mOpacityHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "opValue");          
    GLES20.glUniform1f(mOpacityHandle, 1.0f);           
}
```

I've actually copied my entire texture load routine into my constructor and passed it the relevant parameters when creating my quads but I still nothing unless I set the value sometime after the constructor has run!

I have a fragment shader as below:

```
String strFShader =
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "uniform float opValue;"+
    "varying vec2 v_texCoords;" +
    "uniform sampler2D u_baseMap;" +
    "void main()" +
    "{" +
    "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_baseMap, v_texCoords);" +
    "gl_FragColor *= opValue;"+
    "}";
```

And when I create my objects (quads) I have a method where I can set the opacity of the said quad like so:

```
public void setOpacity(float op) {  
    GLES20.glUseProgram(iProgId);       
    mOpacityHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "opValue");
    GLES20.glUniform1f(mOpacityHandle, op);
}
```

However, I only want to have to run my setOpacity method if I want my sprite(quad) to have some level of transparency.  If I don't specify an opacity level (i.e. if I don't run the setOpacity method) I would like it to use a default or 'initial' value (which obviously I would like to be a float of 1.0).

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot initialize a uniform using some kind of `uniform opValue = 1.0;` inside the shader, if it's that what you meant. Even if you could, it wouldn't buy you much because **uniform values are persistent across program usages**. This means that if you activate another program (using `glUseProgram`) and then rebind this program, the uniform will still have the value that you set last time. So you could set the uniform to some initial value right after linking the program, but it would loose that value forever as soon as you change it for some transparent sprite.

It wouldn't even work during a single program usage, since even more than that **uniform values are persistent across draw calls**. Think about it, if you wrote

```
draw_opaque_sprite();

setOpacity(0.5f);
draw_transparent_sprite();

draw_opaque_sprite();
```

How should the program know that you want to reset the opacity to some default value after drawing your transparent sprite. Of course requiring the application to set all uniforms **for each draw call** would be no option.

So you won't get around properly setting up the uniform for each sprite. A usual optimization in this case is sorting your objects by their render state (in your case the opacity, but maybe some other state is even heavier, like the texture or something the like) in order to reduce state changes (like shader changes, texture bindings, or in this case uniform updates) as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for this @ChristianRau, but I don't want to reset the opacity after each draw/render, rather, when I create my objects (for example quad1 = new Quad();) and I subsequently don't then set the opacity, I would like it assume a standard opacity of 1.0.

Comment: @Zippy Well, set it to the default of 1.0 (using `glUniform` as usual) and it will remain like this until you change it, then it will keep the new value until you change it, like explained in the answer. You cannot set a value per *"object"*, because OpenGL has absolutely no notion of any *"objects"*. There is one single value for each uniform of each program and that value is only changed when *you* call `glUniform`. That's the way everything works in OpenGL, it's a state machine.

Comment: Thank you again @ChristianRau, I must admit I am fairly new to OGL so your explanations are much appreciated.  If I create 2 quads from my custom class and then set different levels of opacity on each, if they share the same program and shaders how come they display each with it's own different opacity level? Thanks, I'm having trouble understanding this. Regarding setting the level 'initially' using glUniform, I was trying to do this in the constructor but it won't work, I'm assuming because the shader program, at the point of the constructor, hasn't been created / linked yet.

Comment: @Ziggy You can change the uniform value whenever you want. When drawing something (e.g. with `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements`) that is the point when the drawn objects will be sent through the graphics pipeline and through the shaders and when the uniforms will be used by the shaders. If you don't draw anything, then of course the shaders don't do anything. So bind the program (`glUseProgram`), setup the state (including its uniforms) for the first object, draw it, then set up  the state for the second object, then draw it...

Comment: ...That's how OpenGL works. It's comprised of a set of states that only change when *you* change them and that only take effect when you actually render something with a draw command. OpenGL doesn't have any notion of abstract scene objects. When you draw something its vertices will be passed through the graphics pipeline and rendered to screen using OpenGL's current state (active textures, active program, its uniforms, global states, ...) and after the vertices are drawn OpenGL completely forgets about them and next frame everything starts anew.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianRau, still not sure I understand because I only set the opacity (ie my uniform), once for each instance of my Quad object, (actutally in onSurfaceCreated), just after the objects has been created.  Not every render cycle. And it retains the correct value for each of the quads even though I don't set the value each time..? And the value doesn't seem to get to the shader when I sent it through in the constructor.

Comment: *"I only set the opacity (ie my uniform), once for each instance of my Quad object, after the objects has been created. Not every render cycle?"* - That won't work. *"And it retains the correct value for each of the quads even though I don't set the value each time..?"* - That may be by coincidence, as it retains it's value across frames, but not per-object (since there are no objects for GL)

Comment: Are you saying that when using OpenGL the rules about java objects don't apply? (ie I have my shaders and program in my quad class, but every 'object' I create uses the same ones?  Just so I'm clear on this as I find it pretty confusing!

Comment: *"And the value doesn't seem to get to the shader when I sent it through in the constructor."* - Because `glUniform` only works if the corresponding program is active (`glUseProgram` used with it). Maybe in your constructor it isn't (or it doesn't even exist yet?).

Comment: I certainy seems to work!! (setting different opacity, size, rotation values) for each of my 'objects' even if its not supposed to!!  But yeah think you're right re the program not being available in the constructor!

Comment: @Zippy OpenGL doesn't know Java or any objects (well, it has something like objects, like programs, textures, ..., but they work a bit different from your usual Java objects). You still have your objects, which might have their own opacity values (as normal float members). But when you draw them you have to set those opacity values as uniforms for the active shader. OpenGL is not a scene management library, it just draws completely unrelated simple primitives (points, lines and triangles) to the screen using its current state, nothing else...

Comment: @Zippy ...Any additional object and scene management is completely your responsibility.